# Why I am getting intendation error for this piece of python code?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand, how local and global variables work in python, Here is my code

```
def f(s): 

    print s
    global s
    print s

s = "I hate spam." 
f('aa')
```

On Running the script, here is the error I am getting

```
 File "global_local.py", line 4
global s
       ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Can anyone explain to me why is that?

Comment: You may be mixing tabs and spaces in your editor.

Comment: You can't make this work anyway: `SyntaxError: name 's' is local and global`.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I wrote the coed to trigger that error itself, but got this error instead. That is why i posted it here

Answer (score 2):

This is your code:

```
def f(s):·

-T--print s
····global s
····print s

s = "I hate spam." 
f('aa')
```

`·` represents single spaces, and `-T--` is a tab.

As you can see, you are mixing tabs and spaces. Python groups these into the following:

```
<INDENT1>print s
<INDENT2>global s
<INDENT2>print s
```

So the `print s` is indented after the `def f(s):` so that becomes the body of the function. Now, the next indent does not match the indent for the function body, so Python assumes that this is no longer part of the function body. So it must be from the outer level.

But the indentation does not match the outer level indentation (which isn’t indented at all), so you get the error.

To fix this, make sure you use the same kind of indentation everywhere. It doesn’t really matter whether you use tabs or spaces, but you should try to be consistent and use *either* to avoid these kind of errors.